# jquery и height()

Tags: jquery, height

народ, столкнулся с проблемой, не пойму в чем дело?

пишу `$("#helper").height();` - возвращает hull

оборачиваю в `jQuery(document).ready(function (){` и все нормально!

но мне нужно чтобы эта фича постоянно отслеживала высоту блока!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего потому что $("#helper").height(); исполняется раньше чем создается требуемый объект. А при обороте в  "jQuery(document).ready(function (){" код включается уже после того как все элементы создадутся.

Вывод.
Опустить код ниже запрашиваемого элемента.

Comment: хм, спасибо за мудрость )) я чет сидел тупил, даже не подумал об этом )) будем знать, спасибо! )))))